# GWT RPCServlet - Junit + getThreadLocalRequest

Tags: java, gwt, junit, mockito, rpc

In my RPCServlet I am using the method AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.getThreadLocalRequest() to get the HttpSession. Now I want to unit-test it. I am using Mockito and thought I just could mock everything, but the method is final and protected.

Is there any other way to Unit-test AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.getThreadLocalRequest().getSession()

Answer (score 1):

At the end you are trying to get a Session. In our case we solve this situation doing this:

Using GUICE for getting our instances (making them available in the GIVEN part of the test)

```
public class TestServerModule  extends com.google.inject.AbstractModule {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
      .....
      bind(HttpServletRequest.class).to(MockRequest.class).in(Singleton.class);
      bind(HttpServletResponse.class).to(MockResponse.class).in(Singleton.class);
      ....
    }

    ....

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    RequestUtil getRequestUtil(final HttpServletRequest req, final HttpServletResponse resp) {

      return new RequestUtilsImpl() {
        public HttpServletRequest getThreadRequest() {
          return req;
        }

        public HttpServletResponse getThreadResponse() {
          return resp;
        }
      };
    }
```

`RequestUitl` object contains everything related with Session and more server stuff (that is not important for your problem :D). The important part here is you can have access to the `getThreadRequest()`, so you have access to `getSession()` method.

What is the problem? You can not have a real `HttpServletRequest` object in your instances, so you need to mock them. For doing it, we specified the bind rules at the top.

At the end your test should be something like:

```
@RunWith(...)
@GuiceModules({TestServerModule.class, ....})
public class YourTest extends junit.framework.TestCase {

  @Inject RequestUtil requestUtil;
  ....

  @Test public void
  test_session_after_doing_something() {
     //GIVEN
     HttpSession mockedSession = requestUtil.getThreadRequest().getSession();
     ....
  }


  ....
}
```

Comment: Sorry for my poor explanation, lately I am very busy, and I want still help others. Sometimes it is difficult for me being active in SO. If you have any question, just ask! :D. Thanks!